# RPI cups server slow on pdf

Tags: raspbian, cups

I got my RPI  acting as a print/scan server and is done by following the guide from
[Print/scan server][1]
[1]: https://samhobbs.co.uk/2014/07/raspberry-pi-print-scanner-server

I am running latest Raspbian lite (no gui) updated every night.
Everything work fine, but when it comes to printing PDF files, it takes AGES. It takes around or more than 10 minutes for 10 pages of PDF to get them printed, while if i unplug the printer from the print server and plug it to my Windows laptop, the same file gets printed in ~2 minutes. Is there a way to speed up this process, please?

I am adding here the output of **lpinfo -v, lpstat -t and lpoptions**

```
    pi@rasprint:~ $ sudo lpinfo -v
file cups-brf:/
network beh
network ipps
network http
network ipp
network https
network socket
network lpd
direct hp:/usb/DeskJet_3830_series?serial=CN8625Q33M06WT
direct usb://HP/DeskJet%203830%20series?serial=CN8625Q33M06WT&interface=1
direct hpfax:/usb/DeskJet_3830_series?serial=CN8625Q33M06WT
pi@rasprint:~ $ sudo lpstat -t
scheduler is running
no system default destination
device for HP_DeskJet_3830_series: hp:/usb/DeskJet_3830_series?serial=CN8625Q33M06WT
HP_DeskJet_3830_series accepting requests since Tue 29 Jun 2021 11:02:53 BST
printer HP_DeskJet_3830_series is idle.  enabled since Tue 29 Jun 2021 11:02:53 BST
pi@rasprint:~ $ sudo lpoptions
pi@rasprint:~ $
```

Comment: firstly: you followed a 7 year old guide - so amazing that works - secondly if it's a Raspberry Pi  or a Raspberry Pi Zero ... (i.e. not a 2, 3, 4) - not surprising really - those original Pi's are not up to doing more than being a novelty

Comment: "Latest Raspbian" is an old operating system. Current is *Raspberry Pi OS*. Printing 2 minutes for a PDF file? How many pages? What size? A big amount of graphics?

Comment: Correction on the version. To be more accurate, I am using Raspberry PI OS in a RPI 2 B+. I have given a try with a PI zero W and had the same behavior. The pdf files that i am trying to print have NO graphics at all, simple text with Times New Roman, font size 12, line spacing 1.5, 4 paragraphs on average.

Comment: What printer do you use? Does it support `IPP Everywhere`? Please [Edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/127795/edit) your question and add the output of these commands to it: `sudo lpinfo -v`, `lpstat -t` and `lpoptions`.

Comment: Initial post update with the information requested

Comment: Hm... `lpoptions` isn't shown, you do not have a *system default destination*. Can you please try `lpoptions -p HP_DeskJet_3830_series` and update the question with new information?